# Why in this OpenGL ES example are triangles visible despite being out of the view frustum?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've been trying to learn OpenGL by tinkering with the most basic example here that draws three triangles -
http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/#comment-2164

The full source code is here -
https://github.com/learnopengles/Learn-OpenGLES-Tutorials/tree/master/android/AndroidOpenGLESLessons/src/com/learnopengles/android/lesson1

Three triangles have been defined in the xy plane with z = 0.0

```
    final float[] triangle1VerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, 
            // R, G, B, A
            -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f, 
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

            0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,

            0.0f, 0.559016994f, 0.0f, 
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

And the view frustum has been clipped at z = 1.0 and z = 10.0

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) 
{
    // Set the OpenGL viewport to the same size as the surface.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    // Create a new perspective projection matrix. The height will stay the same
    // while the width will vary as per aspect ratio.
    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}
```

So the triangles exist outside, the view frustum, right? They have not been translated inside the view frustum either.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) 
{
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                    

    // Do a complete rotation every 10 seconds.
    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 10000L;
    float angleInDegrees = (360.0f / 10000.0f) * ((int) time);

    // Draw the triangle facing straight on.
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);        
    drawTriangle(mTriangle1Vertices);

...

}
```

More importantly, when I change the z coordinates of the triangle vertices to 1.0, they are no longer visible. 1.0 is equal to the near plane so it should be included in the view frustum. How is this happening? Is there some important detail that I am overlooking?  Forgive the simplistic question, I am so stuck with this elementary problem then I find myself unable to move forward without an explanation.

Comment: In the example you link to, there is also a view matrix which is set up with the eye Z = 1.5 (so when the triangles have z = 0 they are 1.5 away from the eye position and when they have z = 1 they are 0.5 away from the eye position). Is that still in your code?

Comment: Yes, it is still there. I have not changed anything. I will attempt to explain my doubt diagramatically, making use of a convenient image I found at http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vp0tetowqcpb0p/Sketch23144111.png

From what I understand, the triangles fall inside the viewing volume but outside the view frustum.

Comment: In that case the answer I hinted at and given by Dirk is correct. I don't think there's any distinction between "viewing volume" and "view frustum"

Comment: Yes, the answer helped, although I still have doubts. Could you refer me to some  reading material on why such a translation happens, and what related less obvious facts one should know? I could not find anything about it in any of the articles I have read so far. Also, this is what I meant by viewing volume and viewing frustum - http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/nt/SGI_Developer/books/Perf_GetStarted/sgi_html/figures/aspect.ratio.gif

Comment: http://www.matrix44.net/cms/notes/opengl-3d-graphics/coordinate-systems-in-opengl looks like a good place to start. I noticed in your comment under Dirk's answer that you mention "an automatic translation". There is nothing automatic about it. Your code explicitly asks for the camera position to be taken into account when it multiplies `mViewMatrix` and `mModelMatrix`. Hopefully reading the page I linked will help your understanding. Please note that modern OpenGL and OpenGL ES 2 don't have any built in Model, View or Projection matrices. The only space it "knows about" is clip space.

Comment: ...It is up to you how to transform your model coordinates into this space, but it's usually convenient to keep track of separate Model, View and Projection transformations as in the example you are working from.

Comment: After going through this article, I think this information was there in every tutorial I had gone through in the sense that the final MVP matrix is a product of the individual matrices. I had not really visualized the mathematics at work here. For the past few days I have been experimenting with the code focusing on the calculations, and that has helped a lot, although I still get stuck plenty of times. Thank you very much for your clear answer and the useful link.

Comment: You're very welcome. If it's worth anything, it took me a long time to get all of this straight in my head, but it's definitely worth spending time and study to understand the concept of different spaces and transformations. It does get easier :-)

Comment: It's worth a lot knowing that most people struggle with it initially. Thanks for the motivation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting about your View Matrix: `mViewMatrix`

The View Matrix positions the camera at (0,0,1.5) looking in negative z direction (0,0,-1).
The frustum is in viewing direction. so the near plane is at (0,0,0.5) and the far plane at (0,0, -8.5)

Thats why the triangle at z=0 is visible and the triangle at z=1 is not.

Comment: That makes sense, but is surprising. Every tutorial I have read so far has led me to believe that camera position is specified independent of clipping planes. I Googled hunderds of images and read the corresponding articles, each time the same belief being reinforced. I could never have guessed that they are specified in relation to each other. This is a how I believed it to work - db.tt/OVQ6H1OX

Comment: I still feel uneasy about the idea. Why would there be such an automatic translation when it's not being there is more intuitive? Could you please explain it some more or refer me to articles about them? I couldn't find the right search keywords. Also, is there a GL_ macro to configure this?

Comment: @fubar: those are the near and far clipping planes of the _view frustum_. It does not make sense to have them independent of the view you are using. You also can't disable that. You sould look for the basics of those transform matrices and OpenGL's clip space.

Comment: @derhass Thank you. This makes more sense to me now, after days of experimenting with the code while giving mathematical calculations the attention they deserve.